# Aceitar somente números específicos em um input

Tags: javascript, html5

Possuo o seguinte input:

```
Conta Despesa: 
<input type="number" name="cod_reduzido">
```

Porém ela deverá aceitar somente números específicos (são 30 números que não estão em sequência, como: 3111, 3113, 3130, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faz sentido o seu input type ser number(com o comportamento das setas para incrementar e decrementar sendo que você não está usando sequência. Então eu troquei para `type="text"`, porém eu adicionei um parâmetro chamado `pattern` que valida o seu input através de um [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Como seu caso é especifico com números sem alguma lógica entre sí, você vai precisar escrever o RegExpna unha mesmo ! Segue exemplo com os 3 números que você passou, basta adicionar o restante separados por `|`(OR).

```html
Conta Despesa: 
<input type="text" name="cod_reduzido" pattern="3111|3113|3130">
<input type="submit" value="validar">
```

Comment: não existe lógica, são 30 números distintos que são a combinação de 4 códigos diferentes

Comment: Então esse código vai suprir a necessidade :D

Comment: sim sim, tá marcado como aceito já, muito obrigado

Comment: mas uma dúvida, funciona em todos os browsers?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern